# Angularjs ngInclude directive always gets commented when compiled

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am making a bus reservation system. For that I want to add login page (which is a separate html file), using the ng-include directive of angularjs but everytime I add it, it compiles and gets commented. Also, I have tried few solutions which i found on stackoverflow( I have commenterd them in the html file) but its of no use.

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form" ng-controller="loginController">
    <form action="/" class="login-form" id="myLogin">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password"/>
      <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form" ng-controller="loginController">
    <form action="/" class="login-form" id="myLogin">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username" ng-model="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password"/>
      <button type="button" ng-click="submit()">login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```js
var app = angular.module( 'myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config( function($routeProvider){
 $routeProvider
 .when( '/', {
  templateUrl: 'loginPage.html'
 })
 .when( '/reservationPage',{
  templateUrl: 'reservationPage.html'
 })
 .otherwise( {
  redirectTo: '/'
 });

});

app.controller( 'loginController', function($scope){
 $scope.submit = function(){
  var uname = $scope.username;
  var pswd = $scope.password;
  if( uname == 'admin' && pswd =='admin'){
   $location.path('/reservationPage');
  }
  else{
   alert('Wrong stuff');
  }
 };
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 8% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form button {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #4CAF50;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form button:hover,.form button:active,.form button:focus {
  background: #43A047;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.form .register-form {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container:before, .container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.container .info {
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.container .info h1 {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.container .info span {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.container .info span a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container .info span .fa {
  color: #EF3B3A;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>BookUrBus</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ngcontroller.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CssLoginPage.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="loginController">
   <ng-include src="'/loginPage.html'"></ng-include>
   <!-- <ng-include src="loginPage.html"></ng-include> -->
   <!-- <div ng-include="'/loginPage.html'"></div> -->
   <!-- <div ng-include="loginPage.html"></div> -->
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show your file structure.

Comment: Hey, the problem got solved.Thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved. Actually, i was using my local host at D drive and the files were in D:\AngularRepo\ngWorks\BusReservationSystem\login.html.

So either the src in the ng-include should be of that full path( i.e. \AngularRepo\ngWorks\BusReservationSystem\login.html) or you can host it at that location itself( i.e. at BusReservationSystem) and run.